# Embed Telegram channel feed into HTML page/website

Tags: javascript, html, telegram

I have a Telegram account and 2 public channels feed that I want to embed into a website, Twitter style, is that possible via an embed code?

[image]

For example these 2 channels. Im not the owner or administrator but I believe these channels are public.

[image]

This is what's inside the channel. Can I embed the channel feed as a widget onto a website?

The link for the channel is : https://t.me/engineeringbookk

But this link will trigger the opening of telegram app only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a step by step tutorial.

First, you need to create a bot on Telegram using Telegram Bot Builder.
Telegram Bot Builder is the official SDK from Telegram.
After creating the bot you need to authenticate it on your site
Telegram is using OAuth to authenticate the site.

The authentication is handled by your site code.

In order to embed a Telegram channel, you first need to get a Channel ID. For this you need to create a bot that allows you to get the Channels that are in your account.
Then you need to create a new channel and select to publish it in another bot.
After that you can get the channel ID using the bot.
Once you have the Channel ID you need to generate a Token using your site
Token has an expiration time so in order to generate it you need to store the Token in your database and generate it when the Bot is started and you don't want to generate it on each request.
Next, you need to get the permission from your site.
Using the Token you can embed your channel.